Trouble cropping objects using YOLOv8 bounding boxes in custom object detection project
I'm currently working on a custom object detection project using YOLOv8 and have successfully trained my model on a custom dataset. However, I'm encountering an issue when attempting to crop the detected objects from images using the bounding boxes generated by YOLOv8 and saving them into a designated folder.
The model performs well in terms of drawing bounding boxes when using the prediction code provided in the Ultralytics library:

from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('/path/to/best.pt')
source = '/path/to/image.jpg'

# Run inference on the source
results = model.predict(source, show=True, save=True)

output
(https://i.sstatic.net/BHNcpwZz.jpg)
However, when I try to crop the detected objects using the following code:
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
import os

model = YOLO('/path/to/best.pt') 
source = '/path/to/image.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(source)

# Directly use `img` for the prediction to ensure alignment
results = model.predict(img)

if results[0].boxes is not None:
    for i, box in enumerate(results[0].boxes.xyxy):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, box[:4])
        crop_img = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    
        save_dir = 'cropped_images'
        os.makedirs(save_dir, exist_ok=True)
        
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(save_dir, f'crop_{i}.jpg'), crop_img)
        print(f'crop_{i}.jpg saved successfully!')
else:
    print("No objects detected.")

The output consistently shows "No objects detected," despite successful detections in the previous code snippet. I have verified the model's accuracy with a validation set, achieving satisfactory results.
Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to successfully crop objects from images using the bounding boxes generated by YOLOv8 in a custom object detection project? Despite successful detections, I'm facing issues when attempting to crop and save the detected objects into a designated folder.

You know img, because it is read by cv2, will be BGR and not RGB. I guess this is your problem

I tried your code with my own model and image and it worked correctly.
Can you upload your model and your image somewhere for me to see if I can solve your problem?
